# How to create a before insert trigger on SQL Server 2012 to make sure the data i'm adding doesn't already exists in the table?

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

How to create a before insert trigger on SQL Server 2012 to make sure the data i'm adding doesn't already exists in the table?

The table design is :

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[column_one] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[column_two] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[column_three] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
```

I need to create a method to add data to the table and make sure the "couple" column_one, column_two is unique and not duplicated.

example :

- id : 1, column_one : 'Stack', column_two : 'OverFlow', column_three :
  'is great'
- id : 2, column_one : 'Hello', column_two : 'World',
  column_three : 'you good?'
- id : 3, column_one : 'Help', column_two :
  'me', column_three : 'please'

I have to make sure, no user can add 'Stack'+'Overflow' or 'Help'+'me', but can enter 'Stack'+'me' or 'Help'+'OverFlow' if he wants to.

I thought about creating a trigger (Before insert or instead of insert) but I don't know what to set as a condition.

```
CREATE TRIGGER VerifySomething
   ON  my_table
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO my_table
    do something
    WHERE something something
END
GO
```

**EDIT** : I tried @TheGameiswar solution and I got some problems :

```
"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'my_table' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON".
```

After some brainstorming, I decided to create a constraint on both column instead of creating a trigger on insert.

the final result looks like :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT CheckUnicity UNIQUE (column_two, column_three)
```

Comment: when you save use a store procedure, inside you sp check is data pre-exist. if exist don't do anything else do insert

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER VerifySomething
   ON  my_table
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

insert into yourtable
select * from inserted i 
where not exists
(select 1 from table t where t.someuniquefield=i.someuniquefield

END
GO
```